# Size elements by content in discrete increments with css

Tags: html, css

I know you can set limits on upper and lower bounds of computed width value with `min-width` and `max-width`. But is there a way to let element expand based on content, but only in discrete steps?

For example, I have a button with a dynamic text content, and I want it to only ever have width (in pixels) that is divisible by 20 and is between 100 and 160 (so it could be either 100, 120, 140 or 160 pixels wide):

```css
button {
  min-width: 100px;
  max-width: 160px;
  /* what would I put here to prevent it being, say, 150px wide? */
}
```

```html
<button>Button</button>
```

*I'm looking for a no-js solution here. Chrome-only solution would also be ok.*

Comment: Not possible without js. Sorry. I hope that I am wrong

Comment: You can't make this kind of calculations in pure CSS. Maybe SASS or LESS can help you, but I don't think so. You said `I'm looking for a no-js solution` but I think that you only obtain `js solutions`

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/4uf4eaey/2/ not divisible by 20 but between 100 and 160

Comment: @Dhaval, «not divisible by 20» — but this was the question's essence. Anyway, thanks for trying.

Answer (score 0):

For this I would recommend two things:

1) you can use CSS **calc function**. In that case you would need to establish some styleguide (e.g. button-small, button-mid, button-large). In Css you would use e.g.:

```
.button-small {
   width: 180px //that would be a default value for non-supported browsers
   width: calc(100%-20px);
}
```

While using this, you can affect the class, but you would need to really think it through (on the other hand, using classes and then changing the css on them would make it easier). But it won't be accurate.

To make things more accurate you would need in your case something-like-js:

2) **Use Sass.** If you do not look for a js solution. Sass is easy to learn and provides you with all the main functions that are native to everything (php, javasript ....) Here you can define conditions and use them as you need (e.g. with usage of modulus). http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html - look for: Control Directives & Expressions.

Comment: With any of those approaches I would need to know the size class (small, mid, large, etc) beforehand, and it's not the case, unfortunately.
Sass is (generally) a server-side preprocessor that delivers plain css to the client — so it can't do things plain css can't.

I was hoping for somewhat like [css grid module auto placement algorithm](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-grid-1/#common-uses-auto-placement), but  for element sizes instead of element positions.